# Do US companies have access to check out their job applicants immigration status?

Tags: background-check

I am wondering do companies in USA have access to a database to check if a job applicant has a US Green Card or not?

I saw on the USCIS website that if you want to check someone's immigration status, you should have their written permission. Can/Do companies request such permission on their application forms when people apply for a job?

Comment: There is a system for checking if you are eligible to work, and companies are supposed to use it, but it rarely happens because there is no enforcement. To be hired in the United States and to pay the taxes on the income you earn from that job, you have to have a tax ID, which is your SSN.

Comment: Are you referring to e-verify website? Can they extract my immigration information from there without asking me?

Comment: How would they unless you give them enough information to run verify your employment status? Yes, I was talking about e-verify

Comment: @user3486308, You could delay the paperwork, but at the latest, you'll have give it on your first day. If you can't give them the right paperwork, they can't pay you, so there is really no point in lying. If you really want them to find a workaround, or to sponsor you, you have to be upfront about what you're trying to do.

Comment: E-Verify says that it should be checked within three days of the person's hiring.

Comment: The alternative is they pay you in cash "under the table". But then you have to successfully hide that fact forever.

Answer (score 7):

Unless a US company is planning to sponsor a Visa, they will always check each applicants legal right to work in the US.

This check can take different forms. Typically there are one more questions on the application itself, any offer will be contingent on you telling the truth, and when you get hired you will have to provide the supporting documents (Green Card, Soc Security, etc).

The employer will have to file form I-9 (https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-9.pdf) and they should indeed use E-verify (https://www.e-verify.gov/about-e-verify/what-is-e-verify) to verify the information and documents you have provided.

Whether they do or not is up to them, so it's hard to tell with any certainty.

Answer (score 5):

When you are hired, you need to fill out the I-9 form. This is federal law. On that form, you have to indicate what your status is (US citizen, Green Card holder, foreigner with valid visa, etc.)

Once you have filled that out, a representative of the company needs to see your documents and affirm that you have proper permission to be hired in the US. That representative signs the I-9 also. The company needs to keep a log of all I-9's and the activities needed to make sure that they are correct.

E-Verify can be used also. E-Verify returns several responses to the information submitted. Responses include: upload scans of the documents presented or a picture of the person and compare the person against this picture that is on file. E-Verify can also refer the situation to other agencies.

What if a company does not ask for your permission to check this and does not ask you to fill out the proper forms? They are at risk of being audited by either ICE or Homeland Security. They can be fined up to $5,000 per unauthorized alien on the first offence and up to $25,000 per unauthorized alien for multiple offences. Any non-authorized employees can be taken into custody.

Comment: "Don't *mess* with the *IRS*"